# I keep getting 401 Unauthorized whenever I try to login an existing user with JWT, Passport, and Express

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js, http-status-code-401

Whenever I try to login a user through a post request in Postman, I keep getting this error:
[image]

Here is the localStrategy I made for checking if a user's email and password can be verified:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'email', passwordField: 'password'}, function(email, password, done){


    User.findOne({email: email}, (err, user) => {

        if (err) return done(err);

        if (!user){
            return done(null, false, {message: "User is not registered"});
        }
        else {

            const realPassword = String(user.password);


        bcrypt.compare(password, realPassword, (err, result) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            if (result){
                console.log('result is...' + result);
                done(null, user)
            }
            else {
                console.log('result is...' + result);
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid Password'});

            }

        }

    });

}));
```

And here is the post request method in my router file:

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {session: false}), (req, res, next) => {

    function generateUserToken(user){

    return jwt.sign({sub: user._id, creationDate: user.creationDate}, config.secretKey);

}

    if (err) throw err;

    res.send({token: generateUserToken(user)})

});
```

UPDATE: I changed some of my code now to address issues raised. However, now instead of getting unauthorized, I keep getting a `404 not found error` 
[image]

Comment: Yeah, that was a silly mistake. I fixed it but its still not working even with the `const` added

Answer (score 0):

In my case there where dismatch in `findOne()`, User schema has `local.email`, so I needed to search for `findOne({'local.email': email}, ...)`.

Answer (score -1):

Seems the value of `doesMatch` is always false.

I believe you're missing the `bcrypt.compare` doesn't return anything.

It is asynchronous, so, you can't get the `result` using the return statement.

You have to put everygint inside of the callback function from `bcrypt.compare`

```
bcrypt.compare(password, realPassword, (err, result) => {
   if (err) throw err;

   // NOW YOU HAVE THE VALUE FORM THE COMPARISON
   if (result){
      done(null, user)
   }
   else {
      return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid Password'});
   }
});
```

Let me know if it works.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seem to work. Thank you for your help tho :)

Comment: You sad it didn't work, but seems it did. About the new error... Are you calling the right route??

Comment: Yes, the route I am calling is `/users/login`, and in my index.js file, I specify that `app.use('/users', userRouter);` and my userRouter is where the code is. So I don't know whats the problem